# Trackpad and USB mouse frozen

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse

my girlfriend broke her trackpad of her MacBook white 2009 and now she's using a USB mouse. This does not work properly and gets often stuck. Do you think the sto issues are related? DO you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is every possibility the trackpad is still generating data, even if only randomly.

The only two alternatives I could think of would be

- Get it fixed, or
- [Disconnect it](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+Trackpad+Replacement/6338)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to disconnect it as soon as I get an Y3 screwdriver.

Comment: Wish you luck :)